# I want to get the data from many to many table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get the data from many to many relationship table (Tag-Service-Category) like this below in tag/show.html.erb.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :service_tags
    has_many :services, through: :service_tags
end

class ServiceTag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :service
    belongs_to :tag
end
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :service_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :service_tags
    has_many :service_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :service_categories
end
class ServiceCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :service
    belongs_to :category
end
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :service_categories
    has_many :services, through: :service_categories
end
```

I wrote the code like this, but it`s not working.
@tag = Tag.find(params[:id])

```
<% @tag.services.each do |service| %>
 <% service.categories.each do |category| %>
        <span class="category" class="<%= category.id %>"><%= category.name %></span>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

controllers/tags_controller.rb

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
        @tags = Tag.all
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you add your controllers?

Comment: Thank you for your help! yep.

Comment: What you mean it`s not working? Is there a error, or just nothing shows up?

Comment: nothing shows up...

Answer (score 0):

Although you have the db relationships correct, you'll still need to call out the connecting model. Because you're doing a double many to many relationship you'll need to create an in-between array. Try adding this to your view:

```
<% services_array = [] %>
<% @tag.service_tags each do |service_tag| %>
  <% services_array << service_tag.service %>
<% end %>
<% services_array.each do |service| %>
  <span class="category">
    <%= service.service_category.category.id %>
    <%= service.service_category.category.name %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried yours , but I cant get service_categories... 

NoMethodError: undefined method `service_categories' for #<Array:0x007fd1b65e3d98>

Comment: No problem. I made an error. I just updated the answer. Hopefully it will output the category id and name now. I pulled the id out of being a class because it seemed out of place, but you can configure that part.

Comment: Thank you for your help agian. umm... I tried again, but it says undefined method. ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `service_category' for nil:NilClass Is there any mistake in my tags_controller.rb ?